# How can i use checkbox to select the multiple values, inside Select box in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

[image: Im looking for similar kind of dropdown which has checkbox]I'm using ng-options to lad my values inside the select box. At the same time, I want to select multiple values. How can I do that using checkbox?

Note: multiple is not my option. I need it to be a dropdown

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {

      angular.module("myApp", []).controller('test', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.rules = [
          {name:"abc", status:"enable", triggerOn: "none", onSuccess: "on" },
          {name:"abc", status:"enable", triggerOn: "any", onSuccess: "on" },
          {name:"abc", status:"enable", triggerOn: "all", onSuccess: "on" }
        ];

      }]);


    }());
  </script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="test">
    
    <select class="browser-default event trigger" ng-model="selectedRule" 
    ng-options="rule.triggerOn for rule in rules track by rule.triggerOn" 
 multiple></select>

    <div>
      <b>Selected Rule:</b> {{selectedRule}}
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to select multiple values. How Can I achieve that?

Comment: The `multiple` attribute allows multiple options to be selected. The selected values will be bound to the model as an array.  Read [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#select-arguments).

Comment: Hello @georgeawg Please check the above code. I updated the code using  `multiple` attribute but I'm not able to get dropdown and checkbox to select them. When I have gone through the docs on my mobile I'm able to select them using the checkbox in the drop down. On mobile, I'm able to see dropdown and checkbox but not on my laptop. Can you help to fix.TIA

Comment: I created a https://plnkr.co/edit/iyVNUTRb8HsiFrUDp7DC?p=preview using your code. I am not able to understand what you are looking for as `multiple` option is working fine. Can you share the screenshot of the UI which is working as per your expectation in mobile

Comment: @ShashankVivek I'm looking for the same thing in the dropdown. I want to select them using the checkbox in the drop-down. I have posted the image. Please check it

Comment: @georgeawg Can you please help me?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).